# Running Pyinstaller on Spyder IDE (or Anaconda3 Prompt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, spyder

Is that possible to run Pyinstaller on Spyder console or Anaconda Prompt? My Anaconda environment contains all the necessary packages. When I try to compile it on Windows Command Prompt it keeps throwing me errors (see [the post of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710405/while-compiling-exe-from-py-file-how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed) if you are interested)

Here is the program that I want to compile:

```
import numpy as np

ca_ch = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(ca_ch)
```

When I type

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

on Spyder console I have the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-7-084bff695e25>", line 1
    pyinstaller test.py
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's the correct syntax to run Pyinstaller on Spyder console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put an exclamation mark (!) before you enter commands on the console of Spyder. So the command below should work.

```
! pyinstaller test.py
```

Comment: Thank you! I entered what you say and it is running. However I can't see messages log as I did in windows command. Is that normal? Is it possible to see it?

Comment: I don't know much about pyinstaller but maybe there is an option for verbosing. Type pyinstaller --help to see the options you might find something useful. Btw i would appreciate an upvote :) happy coding!

Comment: I would definitely give a check symbol if it works. However it's running for more than 6 min and I'm not sure that it works ... btw which compiler do you use to transform .py into .exe?

Comment: I haven't transformed a .py file to an .exe :)